# Global var in a called Go package

Tags: go

I'm interested in using a Go package that uses a global variable which, for my application, is a key "variable".  Each time I call this package, I want to set that variable (it's exported).  And I'm calling it from various Go routines.  Is there a recommended strategy for sequencing/syncing my calls to that package so that my code isn't colliding on that global variable?

Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/jameshaskell/_sketches/globalvars/testlib"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func gr(i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    testlib.GlobalVar = i
    duration := time.Duration(i) * time.Millisecond
    time.Sleep(duration)
    fmt.Printf("   pause %d DONE\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("      global var: %d should be: %d  TestFunc: %s\n", testlib.GlobalVar, i, testlib.TestFunc())
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i += 1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go gr(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

The package I'm trying to access would be like:

```
package testlib

import "fmt"

var GlobalVar int

func TestFunc() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("GlobalVar: %d\n", GlobalVar)
}
```

NOTE: the package I'm hoping to use (having the global var) isn't mine...

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Sample code would be useful to show what you're doing.

Comment: The package I would like to use is: "github.com/jinzhu/now".  I want to set the global var "now.TimeFormats" each time I call the package.  Or am I just flat out trying to use this package inappropriately and/or dangerously?  I can wrap access inside my own protected struct & method using sync.Mutex... is that good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this variable intended to be used this way? May be there’re some specific setters/getters for it? Does documentation have some info about?

I think code becomes very fragile because you do not control all accesses to the variable. You may serialize access from your code with a mutex. But another lib’s code doesn’t know about your it. Moreover it can change suddenly in new versions or bug fixes.

So I prefer:

1. To read about it in official docs
2. If documentation allows, and I can’t avoid to use it, protect access to the variable with sync/mutex/atomic/channel depending on a task.
3. Prepare tests to cover different cases with the variable
4. Run race condition detector as part of my CI tests.

Comment: Thanks.  Definitely will run race detector.  I'm having second thoughts about using this package at all...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package, but beware the warning there:

> These functions require great care to be used correctly. Except for
>   special, low-level applications, synchronization is better done with
>   channels or the facilities of the sync package. Share memory by
>   communicating; don't communicate by sharing memory.

Or you could use sync.Mutex to protect the variable but this would require wrapping it in a struct or an access function to properly control access.

There is a broader question though which you should attempt to answer - if you set this variable every time you access the package, why is it a package variable at all? Why not instead just pass it in to the function which needs it? Since it changes every time anyway, there's little point in a package variable quite apart from the synchronisation problems it poses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package with the `Value` type